# Blinking multiple items(ex QTableWidgetItem) at the same time

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer, qtablewidgetitem

I am the first to try QThread. So I need your help.
I would appreciate a little help.

I'm making some programs. And I want to add some functions to this program.
It has several cells selected from the QTablewidget, and I want to blink them once for every signal.
So I made a function. Here is the source code for the function.

header

```
class KcBlinker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit KcBlinker(QTableWidgetItem* item);
    static   std::map<int,QColor>        m_lBgColor;

    void    Blink();
private:
    QTableWidgetItem* m_item;
    void    BlinkOn();

private slots:
    void    BlinkOff();

};
```

cpp

```
std::map<int,QColor> KcBlinker::m_lBgColor = {  {KD_BG_NORMAL, QColor(234,240,229)}
                                            ,{KD_BG_SELECT, QColor(158,195,87)}
                                            ,{KD_BG_BLINK, QColor(96,158,49)}
                                         };  
KcBlinker::KcBlinker(QTableWidgetItem *item)
{
    m_item = item;
}

void KcBlinker::Blink()
{
    BlinkOn();
}

void KcBlinker::BlinkOn()
{
    m_item->setBackground(QBrush(m_lBgColor[KD_BG_BLINK]));
    QTimer::singleShot(300,this,&KcBlinker::BlinkOff);
}

void KcBlinker::BlinkOff()
{
    m_item->setBackground(QBrush(m_lBgColor[KD_BG_SELECT]));
}
```

The function inside this function is as follows.

```
void SomeClass::Blink()
{
    QMap<QString,QTableWidgetItem*>::iterator pos;

    for(pos = m_lItem.begin(); pos != m_lItem.end(); ++pos)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem* item = pos.value();
        KcBlinker blink(item);
        blink.Blink();
    }
}
```

If QTablewidgetItem is one, it works well. However, if i try this function on multiple QTableWidgetItems, the functionality will not work. I think it's because of QTimer, but I do not know what to do. Should I use QThread?

When only one QTableWidgetItem is active, both BlinkOn () and BlinkOff () functions. However, if I give BlinkOn () and BlinkOff () to several QTableWidgetItem, only BlinkOn () function is turned on and BlinkOff () is not accessed.

Thank you for reading.
And I am sorry if I was uncomfortable reading. I am not good at English.

Comment: Why do not you use the same timer for all items?

Comment: @eyllanesc It's because it can get signals from selected cells individually.
They can blink at the same time, or blink each other.

Comment: From your m_lItem code is a set of selected items, instead of adding an element to the KcBlinker class, you add a list of them.

Comment: What do you mean your app does not work?

Comment: What do you mean: that does not change the color or do not do it simultaneously?

Comment: Creating many QTimers or many QThreads is somewhat inappropriate, it is better to use one.

Comment: @eyllanesc When only one QTableWidgetItem is active, both BlinkOn () and BlinkOff () functions. However, if I give BlinkOn () and BlinkOff () to several QTableWidgetItem, only BlinkOn () function is turned on and BlinkOff () is not accessed.

Comment: @eyllanesc Okey Thanks for your advice. I'll fix the algorithm. By using only one Qtimer.